# Integration of AGI and its Working in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, agi

I am very novice in asterisk telephony word and trying to learn how asterisk can be used in a professional way for delivering it to the customers.While searching it on google it got to know that `Asterisk Gateway Interface` is the way we can follow and proceed to write dialplans and do necessary changes.Also i got to know that `Astive Toolkit(ATK)` is a java based Tool by which i can step ahead.I have downloaded the ATK toolkit but i dont know how to install it and use it with the asterisk server.

So my question is how to install ATK and use it with Asterisk?

Also what else can i do by using `AGI`.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can recomend you read ORelly's "Asterisk the Future of Telephony" book.

Before use AGI you have understand how dialplan and commands works etc.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Patterns

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+-+documentation+of+application+commands

Different toolkit/sdk for agi can be found on this page:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI

Comment: Thank you Sir for your suggestion.Actually i referred http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI and got to know about **Astive Toolkit(ATK)**.Sir i want to do only sample things and dialplans using ATK for this only i was trying to use ATK but i am not getting how to use it by installing

Comment: yes sir ,and now i want to use it but having problem in the very first step of installation and how to use it?